# Update a Rails model with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, rails-activerecord

I'm barely just starting to learn AJAX. My current ajax function doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Here is the function from my coffeescript file:

```
if $('.clickySeat').length > 0
    $('.clickySeat').on "click", ->
        goobergonk = $(this).find(".presentTag")
        aulaId = $(this).attr('id')
        url = '/aulas/update/?ref='+aulaId
        if goobergonk.text() == "Absent"
            attendance = true
            $(this).removeClass("absent")
            goobergonk.text("Present")
        else
            attendance = false
            $(this).addClass("absent")
            goobergonk.text("Absent")
        $.ajax
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {present: attendance},
            success: alert(aulaId)
```

"Aulas" is a model that joins the "Student" table and the "Seminar" table (I used the word "Seminar" because I wanted to avoid the word "Class"). This is where I'm storing attendance data as a boolean. My goal for this function is that when the user clicks on a div that represents a student desk (class "clickySeat") the table is updated to track whether the student is present. To help the ajax call find the correct row, I've tried to assign each div the id of its corresponding aula. The "Success" alert message indicates that the function is getting the id for the correct aula. But when I use the rails console to check the value in the "present" column, it has not changed.

This code includes "?ref=" as the id portion of the url, because that follows most of the examples I've seen in other sites. I've also tried a version without that bit.

I'm sure that I'm missing a crucial piece of ajax syntax here.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working now. I needed to fix the syntax of my data:

```
        $.ajax
            type: "PUT",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json"
            data:
                aula:
                    id: aulaId
                    present: attendance
```